# Is GlobalKTable equivalent to KTable if num.standby.replicas = 4?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

Suppose we have 4 Kafka stream instances performing a stateful operation and if num.standby.replicas = 4, isn't this configuration equal to using a GlobalKTable instead of KTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really.

It's true that with a `GlobalKTable` all partitions are fully available on each Kafka Streams application instance. But the use case for a `GlobalKTable` is for holding relatively static data that users can leverage for enriching joins with a `KStream`.

Additionally,  you can't perform any stateful operations with a `GlobalKTable`, and there aren't any that return a `GlobalTable`.  So for a quick return to processing in the face of losing an application instance, you'll still need to use standby replicas.

Comment: What I meant is I can expose a GlobalKTable for interactive queries but if I have a state store in each instance and if i use num.standy.replicas = number of instances, isnt it equal to having all the state in one machine and I can expose this state for interactive queries which would have been the same result of exposing a GlobalKTable?

Comment: And, the statement is valid only for 2.6 and above correct? Since, the standby can respond to IQ.